# How to debug a C program which execute bash shell script with GDB?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I build OpenSSL-1.0.2n with -g 386 shared --prefix=/usr option (to work with basic assembly version) to generate shared library libcrypto.so.1.0.0.

Inside crypto/aes folder, aes-x86_64.s is generated.

To perform AES encryption and decryption I used following commands in linux terminal.

```
/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in secrets.txt -out cipher.bin
/usr/bin/openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc  -in cipher.bin -out decrypt_cip2.txt
```

Using GDB, I am able to debug the execution of above command as follow

```
gdb openssl

gdb> set args enc -d -aes-128-cbc  -in cipher.bin -out decrypt_cip2.txt 
gdb> b AES_cbc_encrypt
gdb> run
Breakpoint 1, AES_cbc_encrypt () at aes-x86_64.s:1300
1300        cmpq    $0,%rdx
```

From the above output of gdb debugging, it is verified that **AES_cbc_encrypt** function of **aes-x86_64.s file** is called.

I need to verify, if I use a C program where **system call is used to execute bash script** to perform AES decryption, will the **AES_cbc_encrypt** function of **aes-x86_64.s file** still called ?

```
//test.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 

    int main()
    {
    char cmd[500];
    sprintf(cmd, "/usr/bin/openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc  -in cipher.bin -out decrypt_cip2.txt ");
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
      }
    gcc test.c -o test
    ./test
```

**Will I be wrong, if I say when I execute this C program, it indirectly call openssl library (libcrypto.so) and perform decryption.** So it must call AES_cbc_encrypt function of aes-x86_64.o file.

However, when I use GDB to debug this program it is **not showing any call to AES_cbc_encrypt function of aes-x86_64.o file.** It simply make some calls to /sysdeps/posix/system.c, /sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c etc.

```
gdb test

gdb> b AES_cbc_encrypt
Function "AES_cbc_encrypt" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (AES_cbc_encrypt) pending.
```

So, Here is my questions

1. how to debug the above C code using gdb so that it will stop at breakpoint AES_cbc_encrypt of installed OpenSSL?
2. Should I use other than system call in C program to run those bash command  which will ensure indirectly calling **AES_cbc_encrypt** function of **aes-x86_64.s file**?

Any help or link to solve this will be greatly appreciable.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 , gcc-7.0 with debugging symbol on in OpenSSL version-1.0.2n.

Comment: Why you did not fork/exec(v) to openssl?

Comment: Ok. Let me try exec . I will check whether gdb stops at breakpoint AES_cbc_encrypt in that case.

Comment: @Klaus, Thank you. exec worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I use GDB to debug this program it is not showing any call to AES_cbc_encrypt function of aes-x86_64.o file. It simply make some calls to /sysdeps/posix/system.c

By default GDB will only debug one process (the `test` program) and that process isn't calling `AES_cbc_encrypt` -- rather it creates a new process -- `$SHELL`, which in turn creates another process -- `/usr/bin/openssl`, and only that grandchild process calls `AES_cbc_encrypt`.

Since you are debugging the grandparent of `openssl`, it is entirely *expected* that GDB does not observe `AES_cbc_encrypt` being linked into the process you *are* debugging, and that the breakpoint on `AES_cbc_encrypt` is never established, nor ever "fires".

> how to debug the above C code using gdb so that it will stop at breakpoint AES_cbc_encrypt of installed OpenSSL?

There are a few ways:

1. One way is to modify `test` such that it invokes `gdb` instead of invoking `openssl`:

   `sprintf(cmd, "gdb --args /usr/bin/openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc  -in cipher.bin -out decrypt_cip2.txt");
   system(cmd);`
2. If you can't or don't want to modify the `test` program, you could rename `/usr/bin/openssh` to `/usr/bin/openssl.exe` and place a shell wrapper into `/usr/bin/openssl`:

   `#!/bin/sh
    exec gdb --args /usr/bin/openssl.exe "$@"`
3. If you don't want to do either of above, you could use GDB multiple inferior support. Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html) and [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#index-debugging-multiple-processes).

**Update:**

> I am little bit wondering how it will execute ..exe file

UNIX systems don't care about file extensions (they look *inside* the file, i.e. at the file contents, to figure out how to run it).

Thus you can rename an executable file to *anything* you want: `openssl.foo`, `openssl.bar`, `openssl.exe`, `openssl.orig`, etc. and it will still run correctly.

Comment: During openssl installtion have u used -g option

Comment: @Employed Russiana , the first option proves that AES_cbc_encrypt is called indirectly when I call system call to execute the bash shell command , so I am confirmed now. As I am using linux system , I am little bit wondering how it will execute ..exe file ?  In my gdb , info interiors returns null. I am accepting this answer as it is well explained.